# plotly express choropleth map customizing hover data error: ValueError: Value of 'hover_data_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'

Tags: python, hover, plotly, choropleth

I tried to create an interactive choropleth plot of COVID-19 Confirmed Cases by US State using plotly.express.choropleth, but I encountered an issue as I was trying to customize the hover_data. Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

covtrack_states_hist_df = covtrack_states_hist_df.sort_values(by=['date'])

color_scale = ['#ffffff', '#ffe6e6', '#ffcccc', '#ff9999', '#ff6666', '#ff3333',
               '#ff0000', '#e60000', '#cc0000', '#b30000', '#990000', '#800000']

covtrack_states_hist_df = covtrack_states_hist_df.astype({'positive': str, 'death': str, 'test': str})
covtrack_states_hist_df['text'] = 'Confirmed: ' + covtrack_states_hist_df['positive'] + '<br>' + \ 
                                  'Deaths: ' + covtrack_states_hist_df['death'] + '<br>' + \
                                  'Tests: ' + covtrack_states_hist_df['test']
text = covtrack_states_hist_df['text'].tolist()

covtrack_states_hist_df[['positive', 'death', 'test']] = covtrack_states_hist_df[['positive', 'death', 'test']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

fig = px.choropleth(
    covtrack_states_hist_df,
    color='positive',
    locations='state',             
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    scope='usa',
    hover_name='state',
    hover_data='text', # I've tried just text as well, but not working
    # I've also tried covtrack_states_hist_df['text'] and covtrack_states_hist_df.text but none of them worked
    animation_frame='date',
    title="Daily New COVID-19 Confirmed Cases",
    color_continuous_scale= color_scale, 
)

fig['layout'].pop('updatemenus')

fig.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Value of 'hover_data_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. 
Expected one of ['date', 'state', 'fips', 'positive', 'death', 'test', 'datetime', 'text'] but received: t
```

Here is a screenshot of what my DataFrame looks like:
[DataFrame info and head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4PLS.png)

Answer (score 6):

just set:

```
hover_data=['text']
```

it is expecting a list

Comment: But doesn't the hover_data now include the word "text" followed by the three lines we just created?

As in, text = Confirmed: xxxxx
          Deaths: yyy,
          Tests: zzzzzzzz?

Is there a way to obtain *only* Confirmed, Deaths and Tests?